# Using Moment to output Date.UTC() object for HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts, momentjs

I know that Highcharts can take Unix Offset time natively, but it's more readable to pass it a Date object:

```
Date.UTC(2003,8,25)
```

Is there any way for Moment.js to output this exact object?

```
var momentDate = moment.utc([2003, 08, 25]);
var JSDate = momentDate.toDate();
//Not sure where to go to actually output Date.UTC(2003,8,25)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think there may be some confusion as to the functionality of `Date.UTC`.

[`Date.UTC()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp) does not return a Date object. It returns the number of milliseconds between a specified date and midnight of January 1, 1970, according to universal time. This is exactly what Highcharts wants. As you suggest, it is way more human-readable than typing the number of milliseconds itself. For example:

```
var d = Date.UTC(2012,02,30);
// d holds the value 1333065600000
```

Similar functionality in Moment.js can be achieved with the [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-offset/) method:

```
var d = moment.utc([2012,02,30]).valueOf();
// d holds the value 1333065600000
```

Comment: Gah, thanks! I get it now. `Date.UTC(2003,8,25)` is exactly equal and an equivalent substitute to the number `1064448000000` because that number is what `Date.UTC(2003,8,25)` outputs.

Comment: I had the same issues until I read this answer, which lead me to a correct conversion: moment.utc([2003, 08, 25]).unix()*1000