# I cannot plot date with other values, its not taking my date as a date format

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

The problem I am facing is that I cannot plot the graph with the date that I have in my data set, it is not considering them as a date due them being plotted in a weird way.

Currently the x axis is showing date 1st June 1970 but if it considers the date that I want to give then it would be perfect.

Here is the code:

```
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
       processed_json.push([moment(data[i].day,"DD-MM-YYYY"),       data[i].visitors]);
       // processed_json1.push([data[i].day, data[i].u]);

    }

    $('#container').highcharts({

          chart: {
              type: 'line'
          },

        title: {
            text: 'Daily visits at www.highcharts.com'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',

            tickWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 3,
                y: -3,
                formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b', this.value * 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); 
                  }
            }

        },

        yAxis: [{ // left y axis
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 3,
                y: 16,
                format: '{value:.,0f}'
            },
            showFirstLabel: false
        }, { // right y axis
            linkedTo: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3,
                y: 16,
                format: '{value:.,0f}'
            },
            showFirstLabel: false
        }],

        legend: {
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 0
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true,
            xDateFormat: '%A, %b %e, %Y'

        },



        series: [{
            name: 'impressions',
           data: processed_json},
           {
               name: 'clicks',
               data: processed_json1
               }
        ]
```

Here is the data:

```
[
    {"day":"11,10,2016","visitors":918,"u":123},
    {"day":"12,10,2016","visitors":980,"u":203},
    {"day":"13,10,2016","visitors":928,"u":103},
    {"day":"14,10,2016","visitors":928,"u":523},
    {"day":"15,10,2016","visitors":928,"u":300},
    {"day":"16,10,2016","visitors":918,"u":120},
    {"day":"17,10,2016","visitors":983,"u":223}
]
```

Comment: You have data: processed_json1 which should be processed_json AFAICT? Make sure your code does not have a typo.

Comment: Don't know much about moment(),  but this answer might help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27333305/1211981

Comment: So, what is the output of **processed_json1**?  Dates in Highcharts need to be either an integer representing epoch timestamp (in miliseconds), or a Date.UTC object.